# App Store app updates: force uninstalling the previous version

Tags: ios, app-store, updates, uninstallation

I have a question regarding App Store published apps. I'm about to submit an iOS app and I wonder if, when submitting future app updates, it is possible to force the previous version to be uninstalled before installing the update? How are updates managed?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want this? What is your goal?

Comment: @rmaddy Above all I ask this in case future app updates have major changes in the sqlite database file and structure

Comment: @rmaddy I found some problems while developing when I made changes on database tables and I didn't uninstalled first the previous version...

Comment: Any update that includes changes to the database schema must be properly handled. I do this in my own apps. When I open a database I check what version of the schema it is. If it is older I run an update script on it to make it current.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks! Where could I find an example of this? What is the correct place to handle these changes: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, or `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method? How could I perform this database update just once per update installation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the app update as an update to the existing app, not as a new app. There is no need to uninstall the old app. The update will replace it.

Make sure the update is backwards compatible. More specifically: preserve the user settings and any other piece of data your app stores locally.

If you really need to submit a new app to replace the old one for some reason, you can use a custom URL (documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50)) to force the user to use the new app.

You will need to make two changes:

1. In the new app: register the custom URL.
2. In the old app: launch the new app by invoking the custom URL as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18)

Comment: Thanks. I'm worried about possible sqlite database changes coming in subsequent app updates: I'm not sure if an app update may cause inconsistence in the sqlite file if the app is updated instead of being firstly uninstalled. What I mean with sqlite database changes is changes in tables fields and/or tables structure, not in data itself... What you are linking is only supported in iOS7, right?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` values are kept after an app update? If not, how could I keep them?

Comment: Is there any Apple's documentation dealing with management of app updates, how to handle them and how to make updates backwards compatible and this stuff?

Comment: All your app data is preserved. If you make changes to the tables/fields, it's up to you to handle the update correctly. To submit updates:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ShippingandUpdatingYourApp/ShippingandUpdatingYourApp.html

Answer (score -1):

I find that you are worried about sqlite database changes.You can change the name of the sqlite file in new version project.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where could I find an example of handling this?